# Updating Django Forms Dynamically

Tags: python, django, jquery-chosen

I have a simple form that provides a drop down menu of all available entries in a django Model.

forms.py

```
class SampleNameLookupForm(forms.Form):
    #Make a list of sample name options for dropdown menu.
    # Turn that into a list of tuples for ChoiceField.
    samples = Sample.objects.all()
    sample_list = [i.sample_name for i in samples]
    sample_tuple = [(i, i) for i in sample_list]
    Sample_Name = chosenforms.ChosenChoiceField(sample_tuple)
```

models.py

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    sample_ID = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sample_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sample_ID

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
```

When I add a new sample to the model, I can see the new addition when accessing the model in mysql, or in the python manage.py shell, but it does not appear in the chosen field drop down menu.

When I restart the server, the form then reflects the new sample in the drop down menu. How can I update the drop down menu without restarting the server?

I should mention I am just locally hosting and am currently not in production.

Comment: You should put that code inside the form's `__init__` method, not directly in the class body.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example? I seem to be getting some errors when I try this.

Answer (score 2):

The code needs to be inside the form's `__init__` method, rather than directly in the class body, since the method is evaluated on each form instantation, rather than only when the class is defined.

```
class SampleNameLookupForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self):
        #Make a list of sample name options for dropdown menu.
        # Turn that into a list of tuples for ChoiceField.
        samples = Sample.objects.all().values_list('sample_name', flat=True)
        sample_tuple = [(i, i) for i in samples]
        self.fields['Sample_Name'] = chosenforms.ChosenChoiceField(sample_tuple)
```

Also note, I don't know what `ChosenChoiceField` is, but the standard Django forms library has a `ModelChoiceField` which is intended specifically for this use; it takes a `queryset` argument which is lazily evaluated, and therefore avoids the need for the `__init__` stuff.

Comment: [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) adds a little more functionality to the drop down menu.

Comment: OK, well if you're using django-chosen, you should be using the `ChosenModelChoiceField`, which does the same thing and again avoids the need to much about with `__init__`.

Comment: Yeah I use this option for all my other forms, but I don't know how to establish the proper query set for this particular form, soince Sample.objects.all() will not give me the sample names, but rather, the sample ID

Comment: No, Sample.objects.all() gives you the Sample objects themselves. ModelChoiceField uses the id and the unicode representation to generate the field.

Comment: So how would I access a queryset that provides a list of the sample names?